# .on('keyup', ..) not executing on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues figuring out why keyup event is not working in the following situation (alert is not displayed), am using bootstrap 3 for forms, but I don't think `form-control` cancels keyup?

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="visit_adults_number" id="visit_adults_number" class="form-control">
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#visit_adults_number').on('keyup', function(){
        alert('Adult age');
    });

}); /* END DOCUMENT READY */
```

Comment: It works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/j5yxcqy8/, problem seems to be somewhere else

Comment: what does the `console` say?

Comment: @Sadikhasan forces code to respect ecmascript 5+ practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find on change more accurate for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/z46kox4u/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
'use strict';

$('#visit_adults_number').on('change', function(){
    alert('Adult age');
});

});
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan, I can :) Try incrementing by a mouse ) not the keyboard

Comment: @Sadikhasan the point is to listen for the `input` field change its value. The change may come from the keyboard (`keyup`) or from the mouse (`click`) or from sources that may or may not have any `keyup` events. Therefore - the `change` event is the one to use.

Comment: @skip405 I agree with you, but it's absolutely not related to the initial OP problem

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf, welll... there used to be some comments from another person. Right now my answers to him look truly out of place :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This with "keyup"..

```js
    $("#visit_adults_number").keyup(function(){
        var textinput = $('#visit_adults_number').val().substring(0,8);    
        alert("Adult age")
    });
```

```html
<input type="number" name="visit_adults_number" id="visit_adults_number" class="form-control">
```

Demo is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YUtYu/405/)